# After using dd to write an image how do I mount it to write another file?

Tags: bash, mount, dd

I can write a zipped ISO to an SD card using a command like this:

```
unzip -p "${ZIPPATH}" | sudo dd of=/dev/mmcblk0 bs=4M conv=fsync status=progress
```

The zip I am using creates two partitions - boot and rootfs.

In my desktop file browser (Nemo on Linux Mint) if I click on either of these partitions under the Devices menu each partition is then mounted so that I can write files to these partitions without being a super user.

***How do I do this in a bash script?***

I have tried this but it mounts the partitions as read-only for the user:

```
sudo mkdir -p /media/$USER/boot
sudo mount /dev/mmcblk0p1 --target /media/$USER/boot -o user
sudo mount -o remount,rw,user /media/$USER/boot
touch /media/$USER/boot/hello_world
```

sudo seems to be necessary for those two mount commands.  I don't want to have to use sudo on the touch command unless necessary as that will then mean changing file permissions as well.

Comment: What filesystem is on `/dev/mmcblk0p1`? Why do you use `-o user`? It makes no sense here, it allows user to mount the filesystem. It's used in `fstab`.

Comment: I've no idea, I was just trying to work it out.  I think I possibly should be using rw,umask=0022,uid=1000,gid=1000

Comment: `uid=1000`? What if your user id is not 1000? Do `uid=$(id -u)`. Well, `umask=022` should work anyway, did you try it?

Comment: Give me a break :-)  I'm just trying to work it out...

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
sudo mount -o rw,umask=0022,uid=$(id -u $USER),gid=$(id -g $USER) /dev/mmcblk0p1 --target /media/$USER/boot
```

Answer (score 0):

working answer is [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1018877/ubuntu-mount-image-file-with-r-w-permission/1409363#1409363)

First you need to get the offset of your partition.

```
fdisk -l raspberry_pi.img
```

It will give you a similar screen

```
Disk ready_img_with_imu9255_2compass_balanced_net124.img: 3.6 GiB, 3854615040 bytes, 7528545 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xd9b3f436

Device                                               Boot  Start     End Sectors  Size Id Type
rasp.img1        8192  532479  524288  256M  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)
rasp.img2      532480 7528544 6996065  3.3G 83 Linux


Device          Boot Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
raspberry_pi.img1       8192    93813    85622 41.8M  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)
raspberry_pi.img2      94208 15069183 14974976  7.1G 83 Linux
```

You need  "**Boot Start**" number of the second image **94208**
Now multiply it by 512

**48234496** = 94208 * 512 This is the address you need to boot your image from.

```
sudo mkdir /media/sdcard
sudo mount -o loop,rw,sync,offset=48234496 raspberry_pi.img /media/sdcard
```

Now you can update any file in the image easily.

to unmount

```
sudo umount /media/sdcard
```